# How to create proc tabulate table using proc sql

Tags: sql, sas, pivot-table

[proc tabulate table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1HRfS.png)

I'm trying to figure out if there's a way to create the proc tabulate table below using proc sql.

```
TITLE;
TITLE1 "Enrollment by Plan, Region, and Dual-Benefit Status";

PROC TABULATE
DATA=WORK.

;

VAR rcpnt_ssk;
CLASS pmp_plan /    ORDER=UNFORMATTED MISSING;
CLASS capt_region_cd_desc / ORDER=UNFORMATTED MISSING;
CLASS opt / ORDER=UNFORMATTED MISSING;
where elig_month = &elig_month2;
TABLE 
    capt_region_cd_desc 
    all = 'Total'  ,
    pmp_plan *opt *(rcpnt_ssk=' ' * N=' ' )
    all = 'Total'  *(rcpnt_ssk=' ' * N=' ' )        ;
;

RUN;

RUN; QUIT;
TITLE;
```

I've consulted this reference, https://www.lexjansen.com/nesug/nesug06/dm/da19.pdf, but I'm still having trouble.

Comment: Are you trying to recreate the print-out that PROC TABULATE creates? Or are you just trying to generate the same numbers?  Does it matter the structure of the dataset you create with the numbers?

Comment: Would be clearer if you shared data (or made an example using an existing SASHELP dataset like CLASS or CARS).  Also it would clearer if you showed the result that want for example input you provided.

Comment: Probably but the All option will require multiple queries/steps. Can you pipe the proc tabulate output to a data set instead or do you need to recreate this somewhere else?

Comment: Thanks, Tom! I'm just trying to recreate the output, which I thought I attached as an image but apparently not. It's now hyperlinked at the top of the post.

Comment: Of course there is a way, but what is the purpose of this exercise? Why not use the tools that are intended to simplify your code?  For all SQL you will need macro to dynamically construct the column names, or if you allow for Proc TRANSPOSE you can compute all the cell crossings with SQL and then TRANSPOSE.  Are you using a remote database? Some of them have a pivot capability